# Should I declare my test classes final?

Tags: unit-testing

What is the best practice for visibility of classes and attributes of unit Tests? Should I make all my Test final? Or just their attributes? Or neither? Please, point to resources (books, blogs, etc) to support your opinions. Thanks!!

Comment: What does it matter if your test classes are final or not? Or the visibility of their attributes (if any)? Who's going to abuse them?

Comment: because I have seen legacy unit tests laying around with abstract parent classes and all sorts of dubious constructs. Therefore I was wondering what would be the best practices so to keep our tests elegant for future dev generations

Comment: What's dubious about a test class hierarchy? If it makes sense, it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no best practice for this. My gut feel is "does it matter?"

The only scenario I can think of where it might matter is if you're actually shipping your unit tests alongside your product, for example if you're writing a suite of development tools or something. In this scenario I would suggest that the accessibility of your unit tests mimics the accessibility of your classes (in as much as it is possible to achieve this given your code structure).

This is just for the reason that if someone wants to derive from your class, they may also want to derive from your unit test.

But I've never been in this situation myself, I can't believe it is very common. For example, no company I've ever worked for has subjected unit tests to be code reviewed, on the grounds that this is not code that will ship. I'd say that the same applies to things like visibility, i.e. it doesn't really matter.